# Magento MultiStore Rewrite rules does not works

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, htaccess, .htaccess

I have this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.fashionstudio\.ie [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:default]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.fashionstudio\.ie [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:store]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.cansshoes\.ie [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:cansshoes_en]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.cansshoes\.ie [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:store]
```

Magento 1.9 configured as well..

On the shared hosting account I have cansshoes.ie pointed to fashionstudio.ie ( where the base installation is )
Have been reading dose of the help over here and other sources and all should be working just fine, but it's not... I don't even know where to look at any more..

**If it's could be Hosting issue, then I need to tell them where to look at?**

Please, please advice
Regards,
Kos

Answer (score 0):

use this code in htaccess file .it code is three store  in,uk,us

```
SetEnvIf Host .*in.gifts-24x7.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=india_en
    SetEnvIf Host www\.in.gifts-24x7\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
    SetEnvIf Host .*uk.gifts-24x7.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=uk_en
    SetEnvIf Host www\.uk.gifts-24x7\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
    SetEnvIf Host .*us.gifts-24x7.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=us_en
    SetEnvIf Host www\.us.gifts-24x7\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```